# Ngnix server leverage browser cache expires

Tags: nginx, browser-cache

i am new to ngnix and server can you please help where to put this code for adding expires for browser cache?

```
location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)(\?ver=[0-9.]+)?$ { expires 1y; }
```